# why query from same dataset gives me a different result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, distinct

I cant understand how come basically the same query with the same conditions producing  different result set?   All I am doing is just breaking down by amont size

```
--First query 
select count(distinct  controlno)
    FROM    CatalyticWindEQ 
    WHERE  EffectiveDate >='05-01-2016' AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AND LineName = 'Earthquake' 
    AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
    AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued') 
    and description IN ('New Business'
                        ,'Renewal'
                        ,'Rewrite')
```

Total count: 708

```
--Second  query 
        SELECT  
            'New' as Range,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium <= 5000  AND Description  = 'New Business' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')    THEN ControlNo END ) AS '0-5K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 5000 and BOUND_Premium <=10000  AND Description = 'New Business' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '5K-10K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 10000 and BOUND_Premium <= 25000  AND Description = 'New Business' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '10K-25K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 25000 and BOUND_Premium <=50000  AND Description = 'New Business' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '25K-50K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 50000  AND Description = 'New Business' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '>50K'
    FROM    CatalyticWindEQ WHERE  EffectiveDate >='05-01-2016' AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND LineName = 'Earthquake' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'

UNION ALL
        SELECT  
            'Renewal' as Range,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium <= 5000  AND Description  = 'Renewal' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')    then ControlNo  END ) AS '0-5K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 5000 and BOUND_Premium <=10000  AND Description = 'Renewal' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '5K-10K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 10000 and BOUND_Premium <= 25000  AND Description = 'Renewal' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '10K-25K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 25000 and BOUND_Premium <=50000  AND Description = 'Renewal' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '25K-50K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 50000  AND Description = 'Renewal' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '>50K'


    FROM    CatalyticWindEQ WHERE  EffectiveDate >='05-01-2016' AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND LineName = 'Earthquake' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'

UNION ALL

        SELECT  
            'Rewrite' as Range,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium <= 5000  AND Description  = 'Rewrite' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')    then ControlNo  END ) AS '0-5K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 5000 and BOUND_Premium <=10000  AND Description = 'Rewrite' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '5K-10K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 10000 and BOUND_Premium <= 25000  AND Description = 'Rewrite' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '10K-25K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 25000 and BOUND_Premium <=50000  AND Description = 'Rewrite' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued')  THEN ControlNo  END) AS '25K-50K',
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN BOUND_Premium > 50000  AND Description = 'Rewrite' AND DisplayStatus IN ('Bound','Bound - Issued') THEN ControlNo  END) AS '>50K'

    FROM    CatalyticWindEQ WHERE  EffectiveDate >='05-01-2016' AND EffectiveDate <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND LineName = 'Earthquake' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
```

The result is :
[image]

which gives me a total of: 722

What am I missing here?
And how can I find those records that making a difference?

Comment: Is Control_No unique?

Comment: No, it can be dublicate

Comment: In this case, that behaviour is expected. Just imagine that I'm a visitor of some web site. I visited two pages - Home and Search. Only I visited the web sites, there are no any other visitors. Number of unique visitors per page: Search = 1, Page = 1.  Number of unique visitors per whole web site is still one, not 1+1. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does. Thanks, but any ideas how can I make my results match?

Comment: they don't need to be matched. you're trying to compare apples with oranges.  number of unique member of whole set does not need to be necessary matched with the total number of unique members per sets. Business users usually are aware of it. They know, for example, that the number of unique customers per year is usually lower than the total of 12 numbers of unique customers per month. If you want to report control_no for 'Renewal' where each member is not in New, then you need to implement additional logic (NOT EXIST or LEFT JOIN or NOT IN)

Comment: @Oleg, to make the counts from two queries match you should not be counting `DISTINCT` values. Remove the word `DISTINCT` from both queries. Results would be different to what you have now, but total of the first query should be the same as total of the second query.

Comment: if I take off DISTINCT statement its still producing different result. 165 and 186

Comment: @Anton, could you please send me an examples of how can I use additional logic in order to make those numbers match?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the best that can be done is guess.  When something like that happened to me, I had duplicate records that showed up in more than one category in your second request but were eliminated by the more general request.